# Related to iAd in iphone

Tags: iphone

I have integrated iAd in iphone app based on [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app). Now I am getting text advertisements in my application.

Is it enough to get iAds in application, because [according to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> Before you start adding advertising support to your application, you must first agree to the iAd Network agreement. Further, you must explicitly enable iAd for each application in iTunes Connect. As a part of the iAd Network, you control the kinds of ads that are delivered to your application

Will any one clarify my doubt.

Comment: Could you clarify what your doubts are?

Comment: @Claus Broch : Thank u for your response. I am getting text advertisement by integrating iAd in my application using above link.If i want to keep the app in app store is it enough.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer for this i.e., we need to join into the iAd network while publishing our app. 
Check it , it might be helpful http://developer.apple.com/iad/.